# How to save form input buttons into json file by using either javascript or jquery or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have form(`<input type="button">`) in my html file, so for every input button I need to store those values in my json file/object after clicking Submit button, either using jquery or javascript or angularjs ? I have created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/o1bt6pfk/3/), but I am not sure where I am doing wrong ? Please help me this regard and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not getting your exact requirement but I think you can do some thing like this:

```js
(function(){

var buttonValue = {};
   


$("#submit").click(function(){
 $("input[type=button]").each(function($i){
 var name =$(this).attr('name')     
 buttonValue[name]=$(this).val();
});
});

$("#seeData").click(function(){
 console.log(buttonValue);
});

}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='button1' class='button' name='firstButton'/>
<input type='button' value='button2' class='button' name='secondButton'/>
<input type='button' value='button3' class='button' name='thirdButton'/>

<input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'>
<button id='seeData'>See Data In Console</button>
```

Comment: Hi Anand Singh, Thanks for your reply, my requirement is that I need to store my input types(of button) into json file/object.

Comment: WC so you want to save all value of input type button in json/file when click to submit right?? wait i will edit.

Comment: check edited click submit and then click See Data button and ckech in console.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked it, it's fine, but Can't we get input names here instead of 0, 1, 2, etc like {"firstbutton": "button1", "secondbutton":"button2"} - and how can I display/store if I upload any file here in my json file(i.e uploaded file name/value) for any <input type="file">

Comment: Thanks Anand Singh, It's fine now as per my issue, but I have one query that If I give one <input type="file">,so how can I get that uploaded file name/url here ? Can I know please ?

Comment: exact `url` is not available at client side for security purpose but you can get name by `$('input[type=file]')`

Comment: Thanks you for your valuable support Anand Singh !!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99913/discussion-between-anand-singh-and-dhana).